# Can I edit the properties of System Spacers in LilyPond and double it on the other side of the page?

Tags: notation, lilypond, engraving

I can't find any information about system spacers more than:

```
\paper {
   system-separator-markup = \slashSeparator
}
```

I find the defaults too small, and I would like to put a second separator aligned to the right (so both sides have one)

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you looked at the tilting-init.ly file itself?

Comment: I didn't know about that file, let me check it out.

Comment: @Aaron Okay, I looked at it. I didn't expect it to be a `\markup` , but that seems useful. Should I just copy the `\markup` lines and edit that? or edit the titling-init.ly file itself?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't answer that. I found the file mentioned in the LilyPond manual [entry for system-separator-markup](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.20/Documentation/notation/other-paper-variables#miscellaneous-paper-variables), and it seemed a promising lead. I think whether you copy the code locally or edit the file itself is probably more dependent on your personal coding preferences. Maybe make your own copy of the file for inclusion in your projects and edit that.

Comment: I'll try to make a copy and see if everything goes right then. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, what I did was to make a copy of the `titling-init.ly` in another folder (in my documents), edit some things (please change the name of the variable) and include it in my files with `\include`.

However, It's actually more useful to just copy the `slashSeparator` variable into a file instead of making a copy of the entire `titling-init.ly` and play around with the numbers and else so you can see what they mean.

What worked for me was doubling some of the numbers and adding some extra stuff, so this is my result:

```
NEW-NAME-OF-YOUR-OWN-VARIABLE = \markup {
  \left-column {
  \vcenter \combine
  \beam #4.0 #0.5 #0.96
  \raise #1.4 \beam #4.0 #0.5 #0.96
  }
  \hspace #100
  \right-column {
  \vcenter \combine
  \beam #4.0 #0.5 #0.96
  \raise #1.4 \beam #4.0 #0.5 #0.96
  }
}
```

You can just copy that into your working file or save it in another file and include it. And then add it to:

```
\paper {
   system-separator-markup = \NEW-NAME-OF-YOUR-OWN-VARIABLE
}
```